# Apigility (ZF2) mysql db connection

Tags: mysql, web-services, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I am creating services using Apigility in Zend Framework 2. As according to [its tutorial](https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/first-rest-service) 
it's stores all the data which i `POST` in data/statuslib.php and also fetch from here.

I want to connect it with mysql db so that i can post all the data in db and fetch from db. How can i do this?

Comment: What is the question/problem? Are you connected to DB? You should set your DB param in config file as in ZF2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract from https://github.com/zfcampus/statuslib-example

## Build a DataSource

### Sqlite data source:

First, create a sqlite3 database, and fill it with the sample data:

```
$ sqlite3 status.db < vendor/zfcampus/statuslib-example/data/statuslib.sqlite.sql
$ sqlite3 status.db < vendor/zfcampus/statuslib-example/data/sample-data/db-sqlite-insert.sql
```

Then, configure this datasource by setting up a local.php configuration file:

```
$ cp config/autoload/local.php.dist config/autoload/local.php
```

Next, add the StatusLib specific configuration for a sqlite database based data source:

```
'db' => array(
    'adapters' => array(
        'MyDb' => array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
            'database' => __DIR__ . '/../../data/statuslib.db'
        )
    )
),
'statuslib' => array(
    'db' => 'MyDb',
    'table' => 'status',
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'StatusLib\Mapper' => 'StatusLib\TableGatewayMapper',
    ),
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
    )
),
```